# Do math in mysql select with as

Tags: mysql

Tried to select table with alias and simple math, tried to call the alias to use function in where query, found error

here's the code

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.PONumber,
  p.POdate,
  p.customername,
  p.description,
  p.poqty,
  SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS TotalQtySpb,
  p.poqty-SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS otspo
FROM
  tb_po p
WHERE
  otspo != ''
INNER JOIN
  tb_rls q ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber AND p.description = q.description
GROUP BY
  p.PONumber,
  p.PODate,
  p.customername,
  p.description,
  p.poqty
```

Got this error :

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>
> near 'INNER JOIN   tb_rls q ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber AND
> p.description = q.descript' at line 13

Am I wrong using 'where' query ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to reference an expression by the alias assigned in the `SELECT` list in the `WHERE` clause of the same SELECT.

But the alias can be referenced in a `HAVING` clause.

. remove the `WHERE` clause (which is in the wrong place anyway)

. at the end of the statement following the `GROUP BY` clause, add

```
   HAVING otspo != ''
```

Comment: it works, sorry i just know that having query, still much have to learn about sql..

thx

Comment: There are good reasons for this restriction. The conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated as the rows are accessed. When that is being done, the expressions in the SELECT list are not yet available. But the `HAVING` clause gets processed much later in the query execution, after the GROUP BY operation, and after expressions in the SELECT list have been evaluated. For the same reason, expressions involving aggregate functions can't be evaluated in the WHERE clause.

Comment: the more i know about sql in that your explanation sir :) thx

Answer (score 1):

`join`s come before the `where` clause:

```
select distinct p.PONumber, p.POdate, p.customername,
  p.description, p.poqty, SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS TotalQtySpb,
  p.poqty-SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS otspo
from tb_po p
  inner join tb_rls q
    on p.PONumber = q.PONumber
    and p.description = q.description
group by p.PONumber, p.PODate, p.customername, p.description, p.poqty
having otspo != ''
```

Comment: is alias can be used in 'where' query ?

i got error alias "unknown column otspo", but i already declare that alias in select

Comment: yes, added that too. if the columns are ambiguous (depends on SQL dialect) you'll get an error if you don't explicitly prefix the column with the related `table name` or `alias` ...

Comment: so i use "p.poqty-SUM(q.deliveryqty)" instead otspo ?

*already tried that but got error*

Answer (score 0):

You didnt add "q" table reference name on the FROM line, and JOIN line should comes before WHERE clause. 
Try to replace your query with this:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.PONumber, p.POdate, p.customername, p.description, p.poqty, SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS TotalQtySpb, p.poqty-SUM(q.deliveryqty) AS otspo FROM tb_po p INNER JOIN tb_rls q ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber WHERE otspo != '' GROUP BY ...
```